# How to optimally count hits for categories when filtering with both lucene indexes for orientdb (FULLTEXT and SPATIAL)

Tags: lucene, database-performance, orientdb, information-retrieval

I have a data model where I have two entities **Category** and **Element**.
**Element** have *title* and *description* and *latitude* and *longitude*.

I have a limited list of categories (66 at the time) and I want to get a count of how many elements qualify for the other criterias for each **Category**.

To make this query fast I have an edge from **Category** to **Element** *connectedElements*, but I need to make sure that *connectedElements* are filtered based on the other criterias before I can count them.

My initial query:

```
SELECT $count.count as count, name, id
 FROM Category
 LET $count = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM $parent.$current.connectedElements
    WHERE [name,description] LUCENE 'ipsum'
    AND [latitude,longitude,$spatial] NEAR [59.0032396,10.02395,{"maxDistance":100.50186424414406}] )
```

I think that upgrades of orientdb made sure that this query stopped working, but this query shows what I want to accomplish.

Apparently you have to query the **Element** cluster directly to utilize the indexes? And you are not allowed to combine both FULLTEXT and SPATIAL Lucene indexes in the same select statement? (Incompatible conditions found)

So a recent effort resulted in this query:

```
SELECT $d.count as count, name, id
 FROM Category
 LET
    $a = (SELECT FROM Element WHERE [name,description] LUCENE 'ipsum'),
    $b = (SELECT FROM Element WHERE [latitude,longitude,$spatial] NEAR [59.0032396,10.02395,{"maxDistance":100.50186424414406}]),
    $c = (SELECT FROM $a WHERE $current IN $b),
    $d = (SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM $c WHERE $current IN $parent.$current.connectedElements)
```

The rationale is that I should only have to calculate `$a`, `$b` and `$c` once every time I call the query, but that `$d` has to be called once per **Category**. I was hoping this would be a fast query, but it turns out that with a collection of 7500 **Element** this query takes 13 seconds, and that is too slow by far. The individual Lucene queries are lightning fast, so I cannot understand what takes so long.

I hope someone can help me write a much more optimal query!

Comment: In a similar situation (fulltext + geospatial but without orientdb) I had to resort to search by textmatch with subsequent post-sorting filter by distance, but only the head of the resultset, long enough to include all potenctially interesting answers

Comment: @user3159253 The query would of course look very different if I only needed the first results, but I was hoping that this should be very quick as long as there were a limited collection of categories. Lucene should be fast? And making an intersect statement for combining the results of both Lucene index searches should also be quick I would think.